# Why JSF form maintain the validation styles even if has values on it?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have a form (frmAddPax) to add some users data. This data could be submited manual or vía a barcode reader. When the button "Escanear" is pressed this one calls a dialog with another form (frmScan).

This form read some data from a barcode reader and this data is processed in the managed bean. The data creates an object that is used in the original form (frmAddPax).

The problem is all the form has the styling as there wasn't any data on it, all the mandatory fields have the required="true" attribute.

[image]

If I press the "Escanear" button again and scan the same data it shows the form just fine.

[image]

I think this could be because before the data is ready updated in the form the validation process happend, but as I have seen in some questions the **action** and **actionListener** events happend before the **update** process so I have no clue.

This is the code of the form:

```
<h:form id="frmAddPax"
rendered="#{MB.renderStatus.isRenderFormAddPax()}">
<p:panelGrid styleClass="no-border">
    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText
                value="#{label['manageVipLoungeEntrance.addPassenger.firstName']} />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:inputText required="true"
                value="#{manageVipLoungeEntranceExtMB.passenger.firstName}"
                style="text-transform: uppercase;" converter="upperCaseConverter">
                <f:ajax event="blur" update="@this" render="@this" />
            </p:inputText>
        </p:column>
        ...
        ...
        <!-- BOTON ESCANEAR AGREGAR PASAJERO -->
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton inmediate="true"
                value="#{label['manageVipLoungeEntrance.addPassenger.button.scan']}"
                onclick="showLocalDate()" update=":frmScan"
                actionListener="#{manageVipLoungeEntranceExtMB.clear}"
                oncomplete="{wgvScan.show()}" />
        </p:column>
        <!-- BOTON ESCANEAR AGREGAR PASAJERO -->
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

This is the code for the call that made the "Escanear" button:

```
<p:commandButton inmediate="true"
    value="#{label['manageVipLoungeEntrance.addPassenger.button.scan']}"
    onclick="showLocalDate()" update=":frmScan"
    actionListener="#{manageVipLoungeEntranceExtMB.clear}"
    oncomplete="{wgvScan.show()}" />
```

And this is the code for the widtget that process the barcode read and updates the original form with the data processed.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="wgvScan" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
            closeOnEscape="true" resizable="false">
  <h:form id="frmScan">
        <p:graphicImage value="../resources/images/barCode.png"
            rendered="#{manageVipLoungeEntranceExtMB.showTablePassenger!=true}" />
        <p:inputText id="itbarcode"
            rendered="#{manageVipLoungeEntranceExtMB.showTablePassenger!=true}"
            value="#{manageVipLoungeEntranceExtMB.barCode}" onfocus="true"
            autocomplete="off" styleClass="insertData"
            style="background:#ffffff; position:absolute;left:-7000;" />
        <p:commandButton id="cmdReadBarcode" style="display:none"
            onclick="showLocalDate()"
            actionListener="#{manageVipLoungeEntranceExtMB.readBarCode}"
            update=":frmAddPax :growl">
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:defaultCommand target="cmdReadBarcode" />
        ...
    </h:form>
```

**[EDIT]**
@alibttb answer get me to the solution.

I added a remoteCommand before the button that calls the dialog to listen the scanner.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="refreshForm" process=":frmAddPax" update=":frmAddPax" />
    <p:commandButton
        value="#{label['manageVipLoungeEntrance.addPassenger.button.scan']}"
        onclick="showLocalDate()" process="@this" update=":frmScan"
        actionListener="#{manageVipLoungeEntranceExtMB.clear}"
        oncomplete="{wgvScan.show()}" />
</p:column>
```

And in the dialog with the form that process the barcode I added a **onHide** attribute calling the remoteCommand.
I change the enclouse of the dialog-form to form-dialog as was sugested.

```
<h:form id="frmScan">
<p:dialog widgetVar="wgvScan" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
    closeOnEscape="true" resizable="false" onHide="refreshForm()">
```

Comment: Hi, next time please create a [mcve]. Narrow down to one or two inputs, no dialog less css no panels no i18n vua bundles etc. Way easier to inspect things for us (and maybe you even find a solution yourself. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I'm going to edit the post to make it more readable. Sorry for the inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you click the *Escanear* button is that you are processing the whole form, thus submitting all the fields with empty values, this will cause validation errors, your button is immediate so what happens is the following:

1. actionListener is immediate so it's called first and the managed bean is filled with data from a barcode scanner.
2. the form data is being validated and it's not valid so the inValid flag is set on all the inputs.
3. the response is created on the server containing an update for the form, showing the new values from the managed bean and the inValid state of the inputs from the validation process.

notice that the submitted data (empty values) is not applied to the model as it's not valid.

to fix this, just use partial processing feature on your button, and remove the immediate="true", it's just a bad design.

just replace immediate="true" with process="@this" in the *Escanear* button.

If you're not familiar with partial processing feature of JSF and primefaces you should give it a look.

if you really need to submit the form for validation after the scan is complete then you need to use a `p:remoteCommand` that submits the form after the actionListener is complete:

```
    <p:remoteCommand name="validateForm" process="@form"/>

    <p:commandButton value="#{label['manageVipLoungeEntrance.addPassenger.button.scan']}"
    onclick="showLocalDate()" update=":frmScan" process="@this"
    actionListener="#{manageVipLoungeEntranceExtMB.clear}" 
    oncomplete="{wgvScan.show()}" />
```

and in the other form `frmScan` do:

```
<h:form id="frmScan">
<p:dialog widgetVar="wgvScan" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
        closeOnEscape="true" resizable="false" onHide="validateForm()">
....
....complete your code
```

the name of the `p:remoteCommand` becomes a javascript function that can be called back once the scan dialog is hidden.

**Note** bring up the dev console in your browser and watch the two requests one for updating the form and closing the dialog and the other one caused by `p:remoteCommand` to validate the form.

**Note 1** (not related to your question) that I used the `frmScan` to enclose `p:dialog` this is the right way to do it, the form should surround the dialog not the other way around.

Comment: I have made that change and now there is not present the validation styling for any case (when don't detect anything from the scanner or when all data is fine)

Comment: as I said you need to validate the scanner input elsewhere, it's not the right choice to fill the model then send data to the form after that submit the form for validation, but if this is what you want to do you can achieve using a p:remoteCommand to submit the form after the actionListener finish updating the form using onComplete of the button. I can post an edit if you need that. @JuanEnriqueRiquelme

Comment: thanks for your help, what I need to do is the following: call the form that recieves the scanner string (when you press the scanner button appears a barcode png waiting for the scanner read). When the user reads the barcode by using the frmScan's actionListener readBarCode method. Finally I update the frmAddPax to render the readed values. If you could edit and add the info about thep:remoteCommand will be great. I'm so sorry if i can't explain very good I'm quite new to jsf/primefaces and I have to make some changes on this site.

Comment: the p:remoteCommand works like a charm!. I have to make a change on the remoteCommand's process and add a update attribute to it. Thank you so much!!