# What's the difference between p:resetInput vs p:ajax resetValues=true?

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2

I have seen a lot of answers talking about the use of `<p:resetInput>` and `<p:ajax resetValues="true">` works in the same way.

In this case [Why does my form isn't reseting his styling after render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716888/why-does-my-form-isnt-reseting-his-styling-after-render?noredirect=1#comment101876454_57716888) just the `<p:ajax>` component worked for me.

I have read this posts but they always are treated as the same:

- [How can I apply p:resetInput or p:ajax resetValue =“true” for
  p:dataList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895400/how-can-i-apply-presetinput-or-pajax-resetvalue-true-for-pdatalist?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How can I populate a text field using PrimeFaces AJAX after

  validation errors occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6845800/1848292)

I still can't understand the difference between this two if anyone have some documentation about it I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p:resetInput` was basically introduced in PrimeFaces-Extensions long time before `resetValues` on `f:ajax/p:ajax` existed.
Also resetValues is only available for JSF 2.2+ users, while `p:resetInput` even works on JSF 2.0.

Comment: thanks for that info. I imagine between this commands there must be some improvements. Do you know wich one is the difference under covers between using `<p:resetInput>` and `<p:ajax resetValues="true">`?